# ng build --prod build failed after running npm install in new folder

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

Here is the error getting in prod build

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/var/www/project/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Getting error because new versions of packages being installed after running npm install. Cannot share packages version differences because the list is too lengthy. Its working with `aot false` but don't want to build with `aot false`. Not able to find out which package is responsible for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
npm i enhanced-resolve@3.3.0
```

or add it to your `shrinkwrap.json` or  `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`
or update angular-cli as said Filipe Silva

> We've released 1.2.4/1.3.0-rc.1 to fix this issue

I also had issue with `enhanced-resolve`: angular-cli didn't respect my `--environment` flag

See also this thread

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7113

Comment: angular/cli": "1.2.4" solves the `--environment` problem without needing to install enhanced-resolve. But installing enhanced-resolve solves the problem too :)

Answer (score 2):

1. **npm clean cache**
2. Delete **node_modules**
3. Add **"enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0"** in your **package.json**
4. **run npm install**
5. **rebuild** !

I solved it with this thread

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7113