# Angular 4 app won't work when built for production

Tags: angular

I'm trying to deploy my first Angular 4 app and I'm having a serious issue.

Whenever I try to load the app I get this error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'create' of undefined or null reference
vendor.8f08e50eff049f37e041.bundle.js (1,93870)
```

I have no idea how to debug this.

To build the server I ran the command: `ng build --prod`

I also tried: `ng server --prod` which actually gave me this error twice, as well as the one above

```
SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script
polyfills.3ae08eaf6129a55130cb.bundle.js (1,30944)
```

### Edit

I have reinstalled Angular CLI and created a new app, I copied the old code (the index.html and app files) into the new app and have the same problem.

Just to be certain I created another app, made no changes and ran it.

I can now say with certainty that I believe the problem is in the code I've made. but I don't know where to look, I've searched through (literally) every file that I've made changed to and there is nothing with a `create` property.

Is there a way to build my app for production without uglifying the code?

### Update

I ran the `ng build --prod --sourcemap=true` command and I got this warning at the start of the log

```
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("
[WARNING ->]<template [ngIf]="!isClosed">
  <div [class]="'alert alert-' + type" role="alert" [ngClass]="classes""): ng:///C:/Users/jamie/Desktop/play/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/alert/alert.component.d.tsHash: 4607d21b2e5e9f27bd39
```

Can deprecated code be causing the problem?

Also, the build running at gamerfinder.net/dev is the build I got from the above command, I now don't get the `Unable to get property 'create'` error, instead I get a `syntax error` for each file (which you can see by visiting the link).

The entire code for the app [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/jamiemac262/gamerFinder) for anyone who wants to look at it.

Comment: Can you remove `--prod` so you can see where you get an error

Comment: `vendor` is where you have the external libs of your app, show us which libs you are using. And as Robin said, run without `--prod` and check if you have errors there, if you don't maybe is an issue with a lib that isn't AoT ready.

Comment: Ok, I'm building the app without --prod as we speak

Comment: Ok, there are a bunch of errors related to the back end having no data to return... you can see what I mean at gamerfinder.ner/dev        I completely forgot to address those errors before deploying the app -_-    however, the app does work without the --prod flag, despite the errors

Comment: Ok, There are no errors in the /dev version anymore, but the --prod build (which I have updated to reflect the changes I made)  still has the same error

Comment: @camaron I added a list of external modules to the bottom of the question. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see the error in your site. Can you share reproduction?

Comment: run this: `ng build --prod --sourcemaps=true` this will probably tell you what is wrong

Comment: @yurzui My bad, I'm using the non production build on my website now, I'll put the production build on the dev folder on my server

Comment: I had a similar problem like yours. Its definitely a library that you are using that is causing the error during prod compilation. Mine also worked without --prod. I was also able to pinpoint which lib caused my issue by looking at the errors log during the build. Without you sharing code, libs or full log error, it will impossible to provide any further help other than speculation.

Comment: does it work after ng  build --prod , you can check this answer that i have given to deploy on gh pages the same will be for any other prod build [LInk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45258723/2708210)

Comment: It doesn't work after `ng build --prod`... that's what I need help with @RahulSingh :)

Comment: `Unable to get property 'create'` means that you pass empty AppModule to bootstrap function because you have two bootstrap definitions   https://github.com/jamiemac262/gamerFinder/blob/master/src/main.ts#L11https://github.com/jamiemac262/gamerFinder/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts#L53

Comment: You can also get error unable to find `AppModule.ngfactory` Seehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283334/ng-build-prod-build-failed-after-running-npm-install-in-new-folder/45289501#45289501

Comment: If your js file returns html and you got the error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` than it means that you have wrong server configuration  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260093/node-js-and-webpack-unexpected-token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed your project, but faced a build issue. I solved it by updating the `CLI` to `1.2.7`. This probably happend because you use a fixed version for the `CLI` but use the newest angular version. I suggest you use `^1.2.7` as `CLI` version.

Next I had the same problem as you. It is very easy to solve. Remove this line from your `app.module.ts`:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

It is not supposed to be there.

PS. your code is a bit messy. File names with capital letters, forgotten semicolons, etc. I suggest you read [the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) and use TSlint in your IDE.

Comment: thanks! yeh, I'm having trouble understanding the in's and out's of npm haha (I have a global angular CLI with version 1.2.7 but when I run ng serve/build I get a warning about using the 1.2.1 CLI instead), I'll take a look at the style guide and see what I can do to improve the code :) thanks

Comment: that warning isn't really something to worry about. It tells you your global version is older.