# Angular 4 production build throwing Syntax Errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm attempting to deploy a production build of my app onto an Apache server.
I can do this fine using the development build (`ng build`) but when I try to do `ng build --prod` I get syntax errors.

I've tested the app with the `ng serve --prod --sm=true` command and there are no errors in the console.

How can I fix this error?

(As a side note: Does anyone know how I can get more information than "Syntax error at 1,1")

### Edit

I've uploaded the source code for the app at: https://github.com/jamiemac262/gamerFinder

Comment: What errors are you getting when running `ng build --prod`?

Comment: you can see those in the browser console at www.gamerfinder.net/dev   ---- It's just Syntax errors on each of the files (inline, pollyfill, vendor and main), all apparently at line 1 character 1

Comment: Your error means that your server redirects all resources to `index.html`

Comment: isn't that how you get the router to work? (so I can type in gamerfinder.net/user and be sent to the user page)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260093/node-js-and-webpack-unexpected-token

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495675/angular-4-app-wont-work-when-built-for-production I have already answered about this problem in comment to that question

Comment: Okay so... I need to what... change my .htaccess to return the correct file when it's the inline, pollyfill, vendor and main files?

Comment: I posted an answer, I found the problem, thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.

For anyone who might be having similar issues make sure the base href in your angular `index.html` file is the same as the folder where you are deploying the files.